# Git log between tags fails with specific tags

Tags: git, git-log

I've got a script which makes a changelog for me. And in this script I use git log tag1..tag2. Everything was fine, until I faced with problem

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'abc-5.0.0.11..abc-5.0.0.12': unknown revision or path not in the working
tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
fatal: ambiguous argument 'abc-5.0.0.10..abc-5.0.0.11': unknown revision or path not in the working
tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

I found that between those tags exists another one: abc-5.0.0.11-4-SNAPSHOT - I think this tag is main reason.

List of tags on which error occured:

- abc-5.0.0.12
- abc-5.0.0.11-4-SNAPSHOT
- abc-5.0.0.10

Scripts search:

```
git log $tag1..$tag2 --pretty=format:"%cd -- %s -- %cn -- %ce" --date=iso --simplify-merges --dense
```

How could I avoid this problem?

Comment: If it gives this error it means either the tag `abc-5.0.0.10` or the tag `abc-5.0.0.11` doesn't exist. What's the list of your tags ? Eg run `git tag`

Comment: Edited. It exists, but a bit different in the end. I removed this tags and error disappeared. But in case there would be such tags again I need a correct fix.

Comment: If it is a script, shouldn't it be able to get the exact match from the beginning ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be better if you script will retrieve the exact matches itself, however you can do the following to automatically expand the tags:

```
git log $(git tag -l | grep -F $tag1)..$(git tag -l | grep -F $tag2) --pretty=format:"%cd -- %s -- %cn -- %ce" --date=iso --simplify-merges --dense
```

Comment: Sorry, actually it's looping over the array of tags, which I got from another git log.  Hmm... now I may have found error, needs checking. I sed this tags by some complicated pattern, name of this tag could be cutted or not full and that's why it couldn't find it.